# How to join two files using awk?

Tags: awk

Have two files: 1.txt and 2.txt

1.txt has items and their order in this form:

`item-code|order-value|label`

2.txt has items and their properties in this form:

`item-code|property-A|property-B| ... |property-Z`

For example, 1.txt looks like this:

```
ITEM-CODE|_o_o_|prefLabel-EN-ANSI
6|8719|disparlure
7|3300|acids,-bases,-and-salts
8|3299|chemical-compounds
```

2.txt looks like this:

```
ITEM-CODE|TERM|AV-FTC|DB-PEDIA-IRI|LCSH-1|LCSH-2|LCSH-3|LCSH-4|LCSH-5|LCSH-6|LCSH-7|GACS-IRI
2|positive-sense,-single-stranded-RNA-viruses|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|http://id.agrisemantics.org/gacs/C4028
4|negative-sense,-single-stranded-RNA-viruses|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|http://id.agrisemantics.org/gacs/C3806
6|disparlure|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_
7|acids,-bases,-and-salts|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_
8|chemical-compounds|c_49870|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|http://id.agrisemantics.org/gacs/C29686
```

sample 3.txt (result - see below) looks liken this:

```
ITEM-CODE|TERM|AV-FTC|DB-PEDIA-IRI|LCSH-1|LCSH-2|LCSH-3|LCSH-4|LCSH-5|LCSH-6|LCSH-7|GACS-IRI|_o_o_
2|positive-sense,-single-stranded-RNA-viruses|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|http://id.agrisemantics.org/gacs/C4028|NULL
4|negative-sense,-single-stranded-RNA-viruses|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|http://id.agrisemantics.org/gacs/C3806|NULL
6|disparlure|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|_0_|8719
```

this `awk` function:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==FNR{
    a[$1]=$2
    next
}
{
    if ($1 in a)
        $(NF+1)=a[$1]
    else 
        $(NF+1)="NULL"
    print
}
```

generates:

`item-code|label|property-A|property-B| ... |property-Z|order-value`

if no item-code from 1.txt matches item-code in 2.txt, NULL is substituted for the missing order-value

**How to modify the `awk` function to keep 1.txt on the left (the "constant") and 2.txt on the right (the "variables") and generate a result like this:**

`item-code|order-value|label|property-A|property-B| ... |property-Z`

or, if no property-value is available for item-code, then

`item-code|order-value|label|NULL`

the command looks like this:

`C:\gnu\GnuWin32\bin\awk.exe -f a.awk 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt`

where `a.awk` is the `awk` function above.

Am running awk on Win10 and using double quotes

Comment: Could you please post more samples of input and output in your post as it is NOT clear much.

Comment: will do - 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
FNR==1 && ++count==1{
  val=$2
  next
}
FNR==1 && ++count==2{
  print $0,val
  next
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:"NULL"
}
' 1.txt 2.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk '                           ##Starting awk program here.
BEGIN{                          ##Starting BEGIN section for awk program here.
  FS=OFS="|"                    ##Setting field separator and output field separator as pipe here.
}                               ##Closing BEGIN section here.
FNR==1 && ++count==1{           ##Checking condition if FNR==1 and variable count value is 1 means first Input_file header is being read.
  val=$2                        ##Creating variable val and setting its value as $2 here.
  next                          ##Next will skip all further statements from here onwards.
}                               ##Closing this condition block.
FNR==1 && ++count==2{           ##Checking condition where FNR==1 and count variable value is 2 here.
  print $0,val                  ##Printing current line with variable val here.
  next                          ##Next will skip all further statements from here.
}
FNR==NR{                        ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when 1.txt is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                      ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 and value is $2.
  next                          ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:"NULL"   ##Printing current line and printing value of a[$1] if a[$1] is having no value then print NULL.
}
' 1.txt 2.txt                   ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: @Jay Gray, could you please try above solution once?

Comment: this works perfectly: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==1 && ++count==1{val=$2;next} FNR==1 && ++count==2{print $0,val;next} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {print $0,a[$1]?a[$1]:"NULL"}' 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt`

Comment: you might want to explain your solution so that others can lean from your explanation as well as your solution.

Comment: @JayGray, in progress as of now, will add in a min or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `join`.

**1.txt**

```
1|48000|first
2|67500|second
3|81990|third
4|55000|fourth
```

**2.txt**

```
1|fred|sara|anthony
3|steve|jane|mike
4|tim
```

Then run:

```
join -a 1 -e "NULL"  -t '|' -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3,2.4 1.txt 2.txt
```

**Sample Result**

```
1|48000|first|fred|sara|anthony
2|67500|second|NULL|NULL|NULL
3|81990|third|steve|jane|mike
4|55000|fourth|tim|NULL|NULL
```

Comment: I have tried `join`, just as you show. The problem is that `join` seems to break on large files and produce erroneous results. I'll run `your join` and report back.

Comment: join "chokes" on my files. Do you have a preferred place to paste files? I'll put my samples there so you can see the result. Also, I'm using GnuWin32 `join`

Comment: IMHO there is a bug in `join`. I too can make it work on small tables (rows < 100). But it generates bogus data for larger files. For that reason I only use `awk`

Comment: That's fair enough! I don't use Windows (unless threatened with serious violence) so I can't test `join` there. I just saw you seemed happy enough to deploy `awk` on Windows and assumed that `join` would be acceptable to you too.

Comment: i was wrong. there is no bug in Wi10 GNU join - there was a bug in my data. My original data was in a numerical sort. When I changed the data to a unix sort the join worked perfectly. Thanks for your help @Mark Setchell